# Firestore Querying a Snapshot within a Snapshot?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to listen for any notifications whenever someone has replied to a post that a user has commented on. Below is how my database structure looks.

- **Posts**: (Collection)

  - Post 1: (Document)

    - replies: [user2, user3]

      - **Replies**: (Collection)

        - Reply 1: (Document)

          - ownerId: [user2]
        - Reply 2: (Document)

          - ownerId: [user3]

Currently my code has 2 snapshot listeners. The first one listens to the Posts collections, where a user is inside the 'replies' array. Then the second one listens to the Replies collection, where it returns all documents added that != the current user. When a new reply has been detected, it will set the Tab Bar item's badge.

This currently works right now, but I am curious if there is a better method of doing so.

```
func getNotifications() {
        database.collection("Posts")
            .whereField("replies", arrayContains: userData["userId"]!)
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 70)
            .addSnapshotListener() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                }
                else {
                    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(err!)")
                        return
                    }
                    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { documentd in
                        if (documentd.type == .added) {
                            let dataTemp = documentd.document.data()
                            let ifUser = dataTemp["ownerId"] as! String

                            if(ifUser == self.userData["userId"]!) {
                                database.collection("Posts")
                                    .document(documentd.document.documentID)
                                    .collection("Replies")
                                    .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThan: dataTemp["timestamp"] as! Int)
                                    .addSnapshotListener() { (querySnapshot3, err) in
                                        if let err = err {
                                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot3 else {
                                                print("Error fetching snapshots: \(err!)")
                                                return
                                            }
                                            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                                                if (diff.type == .added) {
                                                    let temp = diff.document.data()
                                                    if((temp["ownerId"] as! String) != self.userData["userId"]!) {
                                                        print("new reply")
                                                        newArr.append(diff.document.data())
                                                        let data = diff.document.data()
                                                        let firebaseTime = data["timestamp"] as! Int
                                                        let date = lround(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
                                                        if(firebaseTime+10 > date) {
                                                            self.tabBar.items![2].badgeValue = "●"
                                                            self.tabBar.items![2].badgeColor = .clear
                                                            self.tabBar.items![2].setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for:.normal)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            else {
                                database.collection("Posts")
                                    .document(documentd.document.documentID)
                                    .collection("Replies")
                                    .whereField("ownerId", isEqualTo: self.userData["userId"]!)
                                    .order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
                                    .limit(to: 1)
                                    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot2, err) in
                                        if let err = err {
                                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                        }
                                        else {
                                        var timestamp = Int()
                                        for documentde in querySnapshot2!.documents {
                                                 
                                            let temp = documentde.data()
                                            timestamp = temp["timestamp"] as! Int
                                        
                                            
                                            database.collection("Posts")
                                                .document(documentd.document.documentID)
                                                .collection("Replies")
                                                .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThan: timestamp)
                                                .addSnapshotListener() { (querySnapshot3, err) in
                                                    if let err = err {
                                                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot3 else {
                                                            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(err!)")
                                                            return
                                                        }
                                                        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                                                            if (diff.type == .added) {
                                                                let temp = diff.document.data()
                                                                if((temp["ownerId"] as! String) != self.userData["userId"]!) {
                                                                    print("new reply")
                                                                    newArr.append(diff.document.data())
                                                                    let data = diff.document.data()
                                                                    let firebaseTime = data["timestamp"] as! Int
                                                                    let date = lround(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
                                                                    if(firebaseTime+10 > date) {
                                                                        self.tabBar.items![2].badgeValue = "●"
                                                                        self.tabBar.items![2].badgeColor = .clear
                                                                        self.tabBar.items![2].setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for:.normal)
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not have only two listeners, but one listener per post for which the user you are interested in has ever replied for. This will lead to terrible performances very soon and will potentially crash you app as Firestore has a limitation of [100 listeners per client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates).

I would advise to redesign your data model:

1. Only one listener on posts that the user has ever replied to (your first listener)
2. On each reply increment a reply counter in the post doc, this will trigger the snapshot above.
3. Optimisation 1: on each action on a post you could set a field `lastactiontype`, which would have a specific value `reply` for replies only. This way the snapshot is only triggered on replies.
4. Optimisation 2: set a field `timestamp` on each action to the current time and only pull the last n (for instance 10) posts in your snapshots, this will limit the number of reads at load time. You will have to implement some special logic to handle the case when your app goes offline and back online and all n posts of the snapshot have changed. This is a must if your app is meant to scale (you dont want a snapshot with no limit on a collection with 100k docs...)

Example:

```
firestore.collection("Posts")
.where( "lastaction", "==" , "reply")
.where( "replies", "array-contains", uid)
.orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(10)
```

Comment: Would #2 not produce the same results? It will still listen to as many as my code.

Comment: The point is that you only need 1 listener with the solution I suggest, not as many listeners as posts... If you have 1000s of posts your solution is just not feasible

Comment: I get what you mean now. But I don't believe there is a way to listen to an increment. Does this mean I have to hold temporary variables in my client and see whether the value was increased? But it would mean that if I log out of the account and initialize the app again, the results would not be returned

Comment: You dont have to listen specifically to an increment, your snapshot will be triggered automatically if any document in the result set changes, including any field change, including increments of course. Fyi I am doing the exact same thing in my app

Comment: I have other fields that change as well, such as Likes and Reports. There would be many extra read calls

Comment: There are many ways to work this around, I have detailed a bit my answer to address this. But depending on your requirements you may have to tweak this a bit (or a lot...)